# Prove there is at least one point $x$ between $a$ and $c$ at which $f''(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a function for which the second derivative *f''* is defined everywhere. Suppose that there are three distinct points $a<b<c$ where $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$. Prove that there is at least one point $x$ between $a$ and $c$ at which $f''(x)=0$.
My attempt at a solution: I'm actually completely lost, but can we say $f''(a)=0$? (is this correct and how could we prove this?) If then, maybe we can say $f''(b)=0$ so a point $x=b$ exists? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use rolle's thm three times perhaps?

Comment: You don't need to show f"(b) is 0 since it might not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

By Rolles Theorem there exists a $x_1\in(a,b)$ with $f'(x_1)=0$ and some $x_2\in(b,c)$ with $f'(x_2)=0.$ Applying Rolles Theorem on $f':[x_1,x_2]\to \mathbb{R}$ yields the existence of some $x_0\in(x_1,x_2)\subset(a,c)$ with $f''(x_0)=0.$